# О проблемах сайта Русский язык

Tags: обсуждение, мета, русский-язык

У сайта «[Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)», который вместе с Хэшкодом мигрировал на Stack Exchange, есть некоторые проблемы. Из всех сайтов сети именно нам «Русский язык» наиболее близок, поэтому предлагаю эти проблемы рассмотреть и обсудить.

1. Участники не активны на [Мете](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/). При том, что трафик составляет около 22000 в сутки, за всё время задано 27 вопросов. Даже этот вопрос я пишу на Мете другого сайта, потому что там я не получу ничего, кроме одинокого минуса. **Вывод: сообщества нет, есть только постоянные *пользователи*.**

   - [Попытка обсудить тематику сайта провалилась](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/177015).
2. Почти отсутствует модерация содержимого пользователями. На всем сайте нет ни одного участника со знаком [Помощник](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/badges/70/deputy), т.е. никто не имеет 80 *подтвержденных* тревог. (однако, есть по [крайней мере один участник](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-area-51/56?noredirect=1#comment140_56), который поднял достаточно тревог). **Вывод: содержимое и поведение участников не модерируется.**
3. Вследствие первых двух пунктов, избранных модераторов на сайте не будет. Просто некому стать модератором.
4. Соответственно, сайт навсегда останется в бета-стадии.

Что со всем этим можно сделать?

Comment: Второй вопрос забыл: Кто виноват?

Comment: Есть показатели, которые могут указывать на проблему (пункты 1,2,3,4), а есть показатели, которые сами являются проблемой: спам,  грубость, преследование участников, вопросы не по теме (изучение, использование русского языка на русском языке), засилье повторных вопросов/ответов *крайне* низкого качества, которые должны быть удалены. Глядя на домашнюю страницу  cайта [Русский язык](http://rus.stackexchange.com/) я не вижу криминала. Пункты 1-4 сами по себе не являются проблемой (они могут коррелировать с наличием проблем). Если у Вас есть статистика фактических проблем, приведите её пожалуйста

Comment: @jfs: Пока не представляю, как собрать статистику, тем более что доступа к инструментам модератора я там не имею. Возможно, через SEDE что-нибудь получится найти.

Comment: На сайте меньше 10 новых вопросов в день. Можно начать со списка из Вашей ссылки: [*"У меня больше 160 необработанных тревог висят ещё с весны."*](http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/questions/54/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-area-51/56?noredirect=1#comment140_56) (что из себя представляют конкретные вопросы/овтеты, помеченные тревогой).

Comment: @jfs: даже такой привилегии там не заработал пока. Спрошу Nicolas'а.

Comment: Некоторая статистика: http://rus.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats   (@jfs Большинство моих флагов: "не является ответом", которые идут в эту очередь и застревают там.)

Comment: статистика говорит что проверки идут: *321
требуется проверка, 13 проверок на сегодня, 2071
проверок за все время* (не достаточно репутации, чтобы  конкретные вопросы/ответы смотреть, нужно `1000`). Для сравнения [цифры для ru.SO](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats): *1 требуется проверка, 34 проверок на сегодня, 12067 всего*.

Comment: Зато у них 95% отвеченных вопросов!

Comment: @TagirValeev у них и отношение количества ответов к количеству вопросов выше. На субъективные и неконкретные вопросы чего бы и не поотвечать.

Answer (score 13):

> Что со всем этим можно сделать?

вероятно, не срабатывает «геймификация»: пользователи не включаются в «погоню» за баллами и знаками.

возможно, дело в специфике сайта: где и при каких обстоятельствах можно похвастаться рейтингом *ru.so*, я себе примерно представляю — например, во время собеседования при трудоустройстве, а вот по поводу рейтинга на *rus.so* — у меня мыслей нет.

может быть, в этом направлении и надо действовать? в смысле — продвигать престижность рейтинга. только не спрашивайте, пожалуйста, как это можно осуществить.

Comment: Интересная идея.